# Streaming K-means Spark Scala: Getting java.lang.NumberFormatException for input string

Tags: scala, streaming, spark-streaming, k-means

While I am reading CSV data from a directory which contains double values and applying streaming K-means model on it  as follows,

//CSV file

> 40.729,-73.9422
>      40.7476,-73.9871
>       40.7424,-74.0044
>       40.751,-73.9869
>       40.7406,-73.9902
>       .....

//SBT dependencies:

> name := "Application name"
>
> version := "0.1"
>
> scalaVersion := "2.11.12"
>     val sparkVersion ="2.3.1"
>
> libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
>       "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion,
>         "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming_2.11" % sparkVersion,
>        "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % "2.3.1")

//import statement

> import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, SparkSession}
>      import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.OutputMode
>      import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
>      import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext, rdd}
>      import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}
>      import org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.{ KMeans,StreamingKMeans}
>      import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors

//Reading Csv data

> ```
> val trainingData = ssc.textFileStream ("directory path") 
>                       .map(x=>x.toDouble)
>                       .map(x=>Vectors.dense(x))
> // applying Streaming kmeans model
> val model = new StreamingKMeans()
>   .setK(numClusters)
>   .setDecayFactor(1.0)
>   .setRandomCenters(numDimensions, 0.0)
> model.trainOn(trainingData)
> ```

I get the following error:

> 18/07/24 11:20:04 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 2.0
>   (TID 
>       1)
>       java.lang.**NumberFormatException**: For input string: "40.7473,-73.9857"     at 
>       sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
>     at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)   at
>   java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)     at 
>       scala.collection.immutable.StringLike$class.toDouble(StringLike.scala:285)
>     at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.toDouble(StringOps.scala:29)
>     at ubu$$anonfun$1.apply(uberclass.scala:305)    at
>   ubu$$anonfun$1.apply(uberclass.scala:305)     at
>   scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:410)   at
>   scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:410)   at
>   scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:410)   at
>   org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalSorter.insertAll(ExternalSorter.scala:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.SortShuffleWriter.write(SortShuffleWriter.scala:63)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
>     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)  at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Exception in thread
>   "streaming-job-executor-0" java.lang.Error:
>   java.lang.InterruptedException    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1155)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Can anyone please help?

Comment: The error message is pretty clear, the string `"40.7473,-73.9857"` is not a number. It's two numbers separated by a comma. You need to `split(",")` it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.@jwvh But after using split function as below :     
    ` var trainingData = ssc.textFileStream(" directory path").map(x=>x.split(',').map(_.toDouble)).map(x=>Vectors.dense(x)) `                 It gives this error:  `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed
 at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:212)`

Comment: I'm only guessing but I rather doubt that you are passing the correct type to the `Vectors.dense()` method. You might try: `.map(_.split(',').map(x=>Vectors.dense(x.toDouble)))`

Comment: @jwvh I did the way you suggested. But it results in a Dstream vector of type **DStream[Array[Vector]]**  which is not accepted by **trainOn** method of Streaming K-means. It needs Stream data of type **DStream[Vector]**

Comment: Did you get a proper result in predictOnValues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a dimension issue. The **dimension** of the **vector** and **numDimension** passed to streaming K-means model should be the same.

Comment: The dimension of the data: first parameter of setRandomCenters (it should be the same as the number of features)